# JS Patterns for repeated code on event listener for UI elements

Tags: javascript

When working with event listeners and UI elements, on plain JS, code blocks are often repeated.

Consider this pseudocode:

```
if main menu UI el is clicked
  toggle class on menu
  if sidemenu contains class
    toggle class on sidemenu

if sidemenu's UI el is clicked
  toggle class on sidemenu
```

This represents a main menu that, when opened, should close a side menu too, if open.

In this simple case, the code block to open/close the sidemenu is repeated.

When there are many of these interacting UI elements scattered across the page, the amount of code that is repeated increases.

I've considered writing some helper functions, such as openIfClosed() or toggleIf() that accept arrays of elements and conditions; or that encapsulate predetermined sequences of this actions, but I'd like to ask which widely known **common patterns** for plain js are used for these situations, please.

I am aware that 'reactive' frameworks help with this kind of situations, I ask for these not to be included in answers, just plain JS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As the UI gets more crowded and complex, you cannot reduce the complexity beyond a certain level, but you can shuffle it elsewhere instead. For shuffling that complexity, there is no one bullet proof common pattern, depends on the application.

Every application is different, go with whatever fits your mind, as long as it is consistent. A non-exhaustive list of mechanisms you may need to devise:

- event management: do you want to attach individual event listeners or a single listener on the parent
- state management: do you want it 2 way (state can change the UI as well as UI changing state) or not?
- rendering engine: do you want to execute UI changes immediately or store them and execute them on intervals (for performance reasons)?

below is an example that uses `Proxy(Map)` to store the state with keys as `nodes`. You access the state via the `node.dataset.name` attribute from the `Proxy`. Every action is a `function` that is pushed to an `array` and they are executed every frame. For 2-3 UI components, you are probably better of attaching individual event listeners. But for larger amount of components below 'may' help.

```js
!async function(_UI){ //this is our closure
  const UI = await(_UI), //wait for the Proxy to be ready -> {div:state, div:state,...}
        stack = [], //functions to be executed will be pushed here
        actions = (name) => { //given a UI name, it retuns a function to be executed when appropriate
          const state = UI[name]; //get the state: {clicked: false, node: HTMLdiv, name: 'ui-2'}
          switch (name){
            case "ui-1":
              return stack.push(function(){
                markDiv(state);
                const clicked = UI.states.filter(state => state.name !== "ui-1").filter(state => state.clicked);
                if (clicked.length === 2){
                  console.log("Both divs are clicked!");
                } else if (clicked.length) {
                  console.log(clicked[0].name, " is clicked!");
                }
              });
            case "ui-2":
              return stack.push(function(){
                markDiv(state);
                console.log("I do nothing")
              });
            case "ui-3":
              return stack.push(function(){
                 markDiv(state);
                 UI["ui-1"].clicked = !UI["ui-1"].clicked;
                 UI["ui-2"].clicked = !UI["ui-2"].clicked;
                 actions("ui-1")
                 actions("ui-2")
              })
          }
        };
        
  /*
    add one eventlistener to check if e.target.dataset.name
    is defined in the UI
  */
  window.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    const state = UI[e.target?.dataset?.name];
    if(!state){return}
    state.clicked = !state.clicked;
    actions(state.name);
  });
  
  //common function in all actions
  function markDiv(state){
     if(state.clicked){
      state.node.style.opacity = 0.5;
     } else {
      state.node.style.opacity = 1;
     }
  }
  
  //starts executing the functions pushed to stack
  //remember: actions -> stack -> consume
  function consume(){
    let action = stack.shift()();
    if(stack.length){
      window.requestAnimationFrame(consume);
    } else {
      stack.active = false;
    }
  }
  
  /*
    Monkey patch the original push behavior
    It essentially starts an engine to execute
    the functions until the stack is empty
  */
  stack.push = (function(push){
    return function(...args){
      let retVal = push.call(this,...args);
      if(!this.active){
        this.active = true;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(consume);
      }
      return retVal;
    }
  })(stack.push)
  
}(
  /*
    get the ui bits you care about.
    Wraps a Proxy around a Map where Nodes are keys and the value is state:
    {HTMLdiv: {name: "ui-1", node: HTMLdiv},...}
    special 'states' key returns all the states
  */
  new Promise(res => window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
     res(
      new Proxy(
        new Map(
          Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("my-ui-elem"))
          .map(d => [d, {name: d.dataset.name, node: d}])
        ),
        {
          get (trgt, prop, rec) {
            if(!trgt._init){
              trgt._entries = [...trgt.entries()];
              trgt._values = [...trgt.values()];
              trgt._init = true;
            }
            if(prop === "states"){
              return trgt._values;
            }
            return trgt._entries.find(
              ([k,v]) => trgt.get(k)?.name === prop
            )?.[1];
          }
        }
      )
     )
  })))
```

```css
#ui-el-1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#ui-el-2 {
  background-color: green;
}
#ui-el-3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.my-ui-elem {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id='ui-el-1' class="my-ui-elem" data-name="ui-1">I report if other divs are clicked</div>
<div id='ui-el-2' class="my-ui-elem" data-name="ui-2">I do nothing</div>
<div id='ui-el-3' class="my-ui-elem" data-name="ui-3">I reverse the state of other divs</div>
```